# Is it possible to return ExpandoObject from web service call?

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamic, asmx

I would like to return an ExpandoObject from a WebMethod, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public ExpandoObject TestMethod(int val)
{
     dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();

     item.Value = val;
     item.SomeOtherStuff = "SomeOtherStuff";

     DynamicallyAddMoreFields(item);

     return item;
}
```

When I try to do it, I get this error:

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object)

And I can't extend the ExpandoObject class, since it's sealed.

Is it possible to do this some other way?

Comment: What about if some java client wanted to consume your method? You should always return well known types. --EDIT:  A Webservice is a contract between client & server. What is the contract here, what do you return to the client? An ExpandoObject which can contain anything.

Comment: @L.B In this specific case its not a concern since clients will read the result XML which will always have the same structure based on known parameters and this WS is for internal company use only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create **your own serializable version** of the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class by inheriting from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) and implementing [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).

The [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) is *basically* a dictionary storing the names of the dynamically attached properties together their with values:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableExpandoObject : DynamicObject, ISerializable
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>()

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return properties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        properties.Add(binder.Name, value);
        return true;
    }

    ....
}
```

From here you can implement any serialization format you need to support, including [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).